# Как применить пулл реквест основного репозитория к форку?

Tags: github

Допустим, есть репозиторий rep_base. Некто делает его форк. Но в основном репозитории были непринятые пулл-реквесты. Как их перенести в форк?

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/syncing-a-fork

Comment: После этого решения в форке появились лишь принятые изменения основного репозитория. А те пулл-реквесты, что висят неприятными в основном репозитории — как их-то перенести и применить к форку?